# jquery input slector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

want to access select list where id starts with sentidd

```
$('.select[id^=sentidd]').change(function() {}
```

It fails. Whats the correct syntax?

Comment: @ahsteele thnx for info. I was not aware of the feature.

Comment: no problem, it's a matter of educating people about how Stack Overflow works. Welcome to the community. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
$('select[id^="sentidd"]')
```

To play with jQuery selectors I recommend using the [Interactive jQuery selector tester](http://www.woods.iki.fi/interactive-jquery-tester.html).

Comment: does this work with the DOM elements loaded at page-load time only?  I actually load it using ajax where select element is having id starting from sentidd1, sentidd2 etc...

Comment: @MalTec That depends entirely on where you place the code. If on the return of an AJAX request you'd like to execute something against the select lists then place the code there. If you want to use the selector to bind to the change event of all select elements you could place the code in a `$document.ready(...)` using `.live`. All that's provided here is the selector to get at the elements how you use that is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  - `select[id^="sentidd"]` - notice the `.` is gone and the new `"`s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the attribute value in quotes.  You also have a `.` before select.  This means elements with the class `select` not the HTML `select` tag.

The selector should be:

```
$('select[id^="sentidd"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your select has a class of select, what you provided [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/XzaHs/).

If it doesn't, try:

```
$('select[id^="sentidd"]')
```

without a `.`.  `.<something>` is the class selector.  No dot means a tag selector.  You can see what I provided in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NbPAY)